# Host seemingly isolated from other hosts on my network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireshark

I came across a weird issue an I need help to locate the problem or at least reduce the search area. I'll give a general insight but I can provide details on request.

I have an HP laptop which runs kali, I use it to check my network from time to time;
I enable promiscous mode on my wireless interface, launch Wireshark and no traffic is captured except from the HP laptop, like promiscous mode wasn't even enabled. After rewieving my Wireshark settings all seemed fine.

So I took another laptop which runs Ubuntu, open up a kali VM configured with bridge (so the kali VM is in the same network of the kali laptop and Ubuntu laptop), enabled promiscous mode on the eth0 interface (ofc is connected wireless with the Ubuntu laptop NIC and the ethernet connection is simulated);

I was able to capture packets from many hosts, the kali VM, the Ubuntu laptop that hosts it, my phone, my gf's laptop... but nothing from the kali laptop, which is odd.

TLDR: a first laptop can capture only his own traffic, a second laptop can capture all traffic except the one from first laptop. Promiscous mode is enabled and yes, they're in the same network.

What can cause this weird behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply putting a network interface into promiscuous mode (allowing it to see traffic not destined for itself) is not all that's needed to capture all traffic on a  network. Back in the old days when we used network **hubs** which allowed all devices to see all traffic it worked but things are more complicated today with network **switches**. In a switched network, the switch is designed to detect which port devices are plugged into and **only** send traffic for that device to that one switch port. (The switch does this by detecting and remembering the MAC address of the devices plugged into each port.) So with modern network switches if you have computers plugged into ports 1, 2 and 3 the computer on port 3 won't normally see any traffic between the computers on ports 1 and 2 even it enables promiscuous mode. Fancier "managed" switches will often have a port mirroring option which allow the administrator to explicitly specify that a port will get copies of the packets sent to some or all other switch ports. Using such an option is also required if you want to sniff all network traffic.

Wireless networks add even more complexity to this. Wireless networks are designed to emulate regular wired Ethernet networks to some degree but there is a huge amount of variability in the details depending on the brand of equipment, the options enabled on the wireless access point and the type of network. Most cheap consumer wireless "routers" are actually more like a hub on the wireless side so it's possible some traffic between wireless devices can be sniffed simply by turning on promiscuous mode on another wireless device on the same wireless network. Other, usually more expensive, wireless access points act more like switches to wireless clients so enabling promiscuous mode on a device won't necessarily allow you to see more traffic.

But there's more complication; most consumer wireless routers also integrate physical ethernet switch ports. So no matter what you do on an wireless client you won't see traffic between devices plugged into those ports (unless you have a port mirroring option that can send the traffic to your wireless device).

It's even more complicated than that. If your wireless access point has multiple bands, for example 2.4GHz and 5GHz, then the connection between the bands likely acts more like a switch. I'd guess that's the reason why your HP laptop doesn't see any other traffic: it's connecting to a different band than most of your other devices.

But there's still more! If you have multiple wireless access points, for example a "mesh" configuration, there's a very good chance you won't be able to sniff traffic for devices connected to other access points because the connection between access points acts like a switch.

Finally there's yet another complication. Many consumer access points have a bare minimum amount of processing power so they will take shortcuts (often billed as "optimizations") in order to seem faster. One common shortcut is to simply drop some processing intensive traffic that may not be necessary for most devices to work. For example, many consumer wireless routers will drop certain types of broadcast traffic so you won't be able to sniff it.

So the short version is it's virtually impossible to actually sniff all network traffic on modern consumer networks particularly if there is a wireless component to the network. So putting one wireless device into promiscuous mode won't give you a complete picture of what's going on. In order to really do it you'd likely need prosumer grade hardware or above and all the hardware (access points, switches, router) likely would need to be the same brand and "managed" as a cohesive unit.